# What should I do when a post has a link that no longer exists?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

If the post has a broken link and I don't know a valid one to edit it. What can I do?

Comment: downvote, flag ...

Comment: @Habib I mean.. still a good answer, but the link is not valid. It just doesn't seem right to downvote it.. This is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211046/why-do-multiple-settimeout-calls-cause-so-much-lag#answer-4211427

Comment: The user is still active. Ping them with a comment on that answer pointing out that the link is broken.

Comment: ohh, I thought it was a link only post...

Comment: I've run into about 10 of these the last 2 days on very old questions.  There should a be flag that pumps them into some review queue rather than flag for a mod to handle.  Seems like work the "community" could do.

Comment: Good suggestion plutonix

Comment: @Plutonix how about instead of having the community fix it, the flag notifies the author instead?  This way, he/she can address the issue without adding more burden to the rest of the community

Comment: @ochi the problem is that the user may not fix it. I tried to ping the user in the answer asking for a new link or something and I got no feedback..

Comment: the user may no longer be active or even alive;

Comment: @Plutonix: the user this question refers to was "last seen 7 hours ago". Granted, maybe he set up a cron job to log in once a day.

Comment: @jongware Im pretty sure he is talking generically, not only about this specific answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it was a link-only post and the link is dead, flag the answer for deletion, with a comment along the lines of "link-only answer and link has now died". It has no value at all any more.

If any parts of the answer don't make sense any more, edit to remove them.

Otherwise, just edit to remove the link. A comment of "removing dead link" in the edit description should be sufficient.

Comment: According to the SO online help, link only posts are frowned upon whether the link is active or not. It's expected that the poster provide adequate text to support there answer and the link is supplemental. A primary reason for this is exactly this scenario where the link could disappear or content radically change.

Comment: Moderators have better things to do than handle link only posts: Do *not* use a custom flag, just use the very low flag.

Comment: @lurker Yes, but if the link is still active you can edit it to improve it (by editing in the part of the link that makes it an answer).

Comment: @idmean Fair point. Edited.

Comment: @idmean I dont know if it is age of post or rep of poster based, but old posts do not have that option.  I get Spam, Rude, NAA and other (mod) as the only option.  There should be some sort of "now this sucks" flag to send it to a review queue

Comment: @Plutonix If an answer has a score of 1 or more you can't flag it for very low quality. - I hate that feature.

Answer (score 28):

In general you can always try the Wayback Machine:

[image]
(the image is a link to its homepage)

Wikipedia:

> The Wayback Machine is a digital archive of the World Wide Web and other information on the Internet created by the Internet Archive, a non-profit organization, based in San Francisco, California. It was set up by Brewster Kahle and Bruce Gilliat, and is maintained with content from Alexa Internet. The service enables users to see archived versions of web pages across time, which the Archive calls a "three dimensional index."

Guesstimate: if every entry for the web pages it indexed in its 19 years of existence (per 2015) was written down in a ledger, that stack of paper would be about 24 kilometers high. Fortunately, all you have to do is enter the exact URL into the search field.

Unfortunately, the link under discussion (https://web.archive.org/web/20111126003546/http://slebetman.110mb.com/tank3.html) does not appear to be compatible with Wayback's storage system. Inspecting its source, it seems the page is built entirely with Javascript, and while the scripts archived as well, it does not work anymore.

Comment: Good answer. But in the SO context, what should be done when a valid link is not avaiable? Should I just leave the post as it is?

Comment: @GabrielMoretti By SO context, you mean like edit, flag, etc? (don't flag)

Comment: @jakekimds yes.

Comment: @GabrielMoretti I have made edits before in updating the link, _especially_ if it is an accepted or top-rated answer. Chances are, you would find that answer helpful, too, if you could see the link.

Comment: "and while the scripts archived as well" -- The script isn't archived. The only "archive" of at least one of the JavaScript files is when it was already removed and redirects to a 404 page.