# "This edit was intended to address the author"

Tags: discussion, support

I made [an edit earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9898482), having originally flagged the answer because of the broken link, and my edit earlier was rejected (as was my flag; hence the edit).  However, having read the following three meta posts I think my edit was valid and useful:

1. The link in the post referred to in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280234/edit-to-correct-broken-link-was-rejected) does resolve; the one I refer to doesn't.
2. The accepted answer to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295592/what-should-i-do-when-a-post-has-a-link-that-no-longer-exists)  says to do what I did, since the user has been notified in February in a comment, is still active, but hasn't corrected the answer and the most upvoted answer says change the link to waybackmachine - but [the waybackmachine version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140319233954/http://jsfiddle.net/PHnLb/7) is very slow to load and gives: `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` when Run.
3. And the first comment on [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258362/should-we-approve-an-edit-which-removes-broken-a-url) says "I would have approved that,  but note that the link was repairable" and in the case of my edit earlier, the post wasn't repairable. (I have deliberately omitted @ referencing the author of the comment, but I am not oblivious to his standing in this community).

So, my question is:

- Was I correct in editing this answer earlier and removing the link?
- Or, instead of removing the link, should I have appended the waybackmachine version regardless of the fact it seems to fail?
- If the answer is that my edit was correct, what should I do to edit this answer now?

Comment: `his standing in this community is not oblivious to me` - Could you clarify what you mean? Did you mean `not obvious`?

Comment: @theB, sure: [oblivious defined](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20oblivious) ie: I am aware he is a diamond moderator

Comment: It's an odd construction. Maybe I just need caffeine, but is it that you are unaware of his status, or not concerned?

Comment: @theB yes, now you have called me out on it, it is an odd construction.  I struggled a little with including that comment and wasn't too sure how to say it, probably mostly because I was trying to say "this diamond moderator seems to be suggesting what I have done is correct".  That's probably what I should've said.

Comment: thanks @Deduplicator but I did double check that wasn't the issue; I flagged the answer a little while ago having double checked then, and edited this morning having double checked again and then before I posted my question here I double checked again.  Even so, I just double-checked one more time, in case I do exist in an alternative universe (as I sometimes wonder) and jsfiddle.net is up for me but the fiddle in question still 404s... But I don't rule co-incidence and am ready for this to be my error.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I can see 2 other comments, first from 15 Feb (8 month ago!)  telling the author that the link is broken, latter from 13 Apr explaining how to use code from another answer. But no edit nor comment from the author

Comment: @lukkea: FYI, "oblivious" doesn't mean "unknown", it means "unknowing". You can say, "I was not oblivious to his standing in the community", but not "his standing was oblivious to me".

Comment: @SteveJessop I just shouldn't've used the word, but I'm a guy who doesn't have a problem with "shouldn't've" and I wasn't thinking I'd be picked up on my grammar by one person, let alone two!  But, ho hum; maybe I'll get more active on english.stackexchange (active in a questiony kind of a way, of course).

Comment: @SteveJessop the penny dropped after some help on english.stackexchange - thanks for making me think harder about this. :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

IMHO, the edit was correct and should have been accepted:

- the comment was *Removed link to us[e] fiddle because it 404'd* explaining the reason for the edit - even if I would have prefered *Removed link because is has been broken for 8 months*
- the author was addressed 8 month ago in a comment and nothing more happened (ok, the answered was written 3 years ago...)

Of course, the way @Deduplicator solved it by resurecting the info through http://archive.org allows the (off site) information to be available again, by clearly the reason for reject *This edit was intended to address the author of the post* is not fair since the author had already been addressed for that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I guess I should make the comment reason more comprehensive and ensure there isn't an archive somewhere next time; If there is a next time...

Comment: @lukkea: The problem here is that the author had a lot of rep, so reviewers could be reluctant to edit his answer. 2 approved (like I would have), but 3 rejected. That's the *mysterious ways of SO* ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, jsFiddle seems to have lost that one permanently.

Still, I went ahead and tried http://archive.org: Success!

Testing a few versions, I succeeded in getting one of the oldest to run. So I put the into an edit.

Comment: Are we really supposed to do that? I assume you have spent some time resurecting an off line content. I am not really used to Javascript, so maybe jsFiddle worths it, but I was just wondering whether it would or not be better to include the js in the answer. I thought that it was the reason for *code snippets* on SO?

Comment: Should I accept this as the answer to my question?  ie: in future I should post a similar question on meta whenever this happens and someone with more rep than me makes the edit that I've taken some time to resolve?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Well, *we* may not legally import the off-site resource, license conflict. Anyway, it was not neccessary for the answer to be complete.

Comment: @lukkea Well, Dedup did *fix* the problem completely.  Had you replaced the link with a working one, I doubt your original edit would have been removed.  As noted in the other answer, when making drastic edits, you have to STRONGLY argue your case in the comment; and even then, there is a risk it will be rejected.

Comment: I get your concern about conflicting licenses, but somehow I don't think that there's much cause for concern in this case. It's throwaway code and I think the intent was pretty clear. I went ahead and edited it in under a layman's vague concept of fair or reasonable use. If the author decide's s/he's got a goldmine of code, they can remove it and chastise me strongly for the evil I've committed.